# MANCOVA or Regression for a Moderator

Tags: interaction, manova

I am doing a MANOVA, and I have a categorical IV with 3 levels and 2 dependent Variables. I want to see if another continuous variable acts as a moderator. Can I simply enter that variable as a covariate and run the analysis, or do I need to run separate regression models for this, while dummy coding my predictor and creating interaction terms? My apologies if this question has been asked, I searched but did not find anything.

Comment: Most modern stat programs allow you to include an interaction of a categorical variable and a quantitative variable without creating dummy variables (the stat program creates the variables implicitly).